# Can you set the current running directory from the java command line?

Tags: java, command-line, working-directory

I am running a Java application from the command line. Can I specify a command line argument to set the current running directory to something other than where the application is actually going to run?

Comment: Not sure that this is a duplicate, but can be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840190/changing-the-current-working-directory-in-java

Comment: Yes, that may be helpful. new File(parent, path) might work. I will have to try it. Reason why I posted this question is I am trying to use a profiler on a dll that my application loads. Since I have to essentially profile java.exe, the current working directory gets set to my jdk folder and throws off my relative paths in my application.

Comment: Your profiler should have an option to set starting directory. Or maybe it is possible to write a BAT file and tell profiler to run it?

Comment: It does, but the application will not run when I set that for whatever reason

Answer (score 44):

There is a JVM argument `-Duser.dir` which can be used to set working directory for JVM.

Comment: Don't do this unless you want some inconsistent behavior in your program. I.e. `new File("file.txt").getAbsolutePath()` and `new File("file.txt").getCanonicalPath()` respect the value of the property. But most of other methods of the `File` do not.

Answer (score 6):

If it all possible I would rather use a script to run the java application and set the directory in the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd <your dir>
java <some arguments>
```

The JNI-solution may affect all kinds of relative paths in your application; for examples the classpath you put in.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the current directory, you'll have to use JNI and invoke a native API from your Java code. For example, for Windows you would use [SetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I am using JNI so this might be a possible solution.

Comment: This would make your code completely non-portable, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I found this SO post and it helped me solve my problem. Though I wanted to share something specific about IntelliJ that might trip somebody else up.

I have posted a picture below where the -Duser.dir flag is used and also the Working Directory text field is filled in.

[image: "Working Directory" field has lower precedence than the -Duser.dir flag.]

In this situation, the Working Directory will be set to "JarLearning" rather than "2ndTry".