# Maven Exec Plugin : How configure the working directory

Tags: java, maven, exec

I'm using the Exec Maven plugin with the following command :

> mvn exec:java

and I didn't manage to set the **working directory** with this execution mode. 
I want to use a mainClass (in a specific package) 
and I want the root folder of my execution in another directory than the ${basedir}.

Thank you for your help.

My pom.xml  where the target **< workingDirectory >** doesn't work for me :

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}\classes</workingDirectory>
            <mainClass>com.package.MyMainClass</mainClass>
            <includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>
        </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

the result with the -X option

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2:java from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2,parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@11b86e7]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2:java' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) arguments = []
[DEBUG]   (f) classpathScope = runtime
[DEBUG]   (f) cleanupDaemonThreads = true
[DEBUG]   (f) daemonThreadJoinTimeout = 15000
[DEBUG]   (f) includePluginDependencies = false
[DEBUG]   (f) includeProjectDependencies = true
[DEBUG]   (f) keepAlive = false
[DEBUG]   (f) killAfter = 1
[DEBUG]   (f) localRepository =        id: local url: file:///C:/Users/100728452/.m2/repository/   layout: none
[DEBUG]   (f) mainClass = com.package.MyMainClass
[DEBUG]   (f) pluginDependencies = [org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:1.3.2:, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus...
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) stopUnresponsiveDaemonThreads = false
[DEBUG]   (s) key = sun.java2d.ddoffscreen
[DEBUG]   (s) value = false
[DEBUG]   (s) key = com.odi.OStoreLicenseFile
[DEBUG]   (s) value = .\library\odi\etc\license.txt
[DEBUG]   (f) systemProperties = [org.codehaus.mojo.exec.Property@194e776, org.codehaus.mojo.exec.Property@e80740]
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[WARNING] Warning: killAfter is now deprecated. Do you need it ? Please comment on MEXEC-6.
[DEBUG] Invoking : com.mypackage.MyMainClass.main()
[DEBUG] Plugin Dependencies will be excluded.
[DEBUG] Project Dependencies will be included.
[DEBUG] Collected project artifacts [javax.help:javahelp:jar:2.0.02:compile,
```

Comment: There is also https://stackoverflow.com/a/9529800/2746335, but that interferes with other plugins

Answer (score 29):

I didn't found solution with exec:java.

So, now I use **exec:exec** instead because we can set the workingDirectory and it' OK.

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.3.2</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
<configuration> 
    <executable>java</executable>
    <arguments>
        <argument>-classpath</argument> 
        <classpath />
        <argument>com.package.MyMainClass</argument>  
    </arguments>
    <workingDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</workingDirectory>           
</configuration>
```

Comment: pitfall: if the directory doesn't exists it fallsback to base dir without giving any info! so check it with `mvn -X verify | grep working`  or similar

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't either find a working fix, however an ugly workaround that was applicable in my case is to simply pass `${project.build.directory}` (or any maven property for the matter) as an argument to the main class and handling it from there.

```
<configuration>
    [...]
    <arguments>
        <argument>${project.build.directory}</argument>
    </arguments>
    [...]
</configuration>
```

Setting the current working directory inside the code to properly simulate the non-working `workingDirectory` configuration is a bit tricky if you insist doing so, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/840229) linked answer for more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to set it via calling `mvn exec:java ...` you need to go via the property like this:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.workingdir=Folder ...
```

which has nothing to do what you defined in your pom cause calling the goal `exec:java` is not part of the life cycle.

Comment: Thank you, but even if I've added this -Dexec option it doesn't work for me, my Main class doesn't find files in my workingdir. I've pasted the result of the mvn exec:java -X command

Comment: What kind of files does your main class searching for ? property files?

Comment: My Java program need a dll in the running folder. This file is in the right place but I'm still getting the same error : missing dll.
Otherwise I've used the surefire plugin for my Junit tests and it works fine for me, the workingDirectory target works

Comment: Property exec.workingdir can be used only when executing via exec:exec.