# How to shift configuration of Mule Project from Intellij to Netbeans 8?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, netbeans, mule

In Intellij, Mule Server is used to run Mule Project but this facility is not available in Netbeans by default.

I have asked Intellij users and following screen shot is provided which contains Mule's dependency class to start.

[image: Intellij Screenshot]

Could anyone suggest how to map the same in Netbeans to run Mule Project built in Maven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Netbeans allows any way to set VM arguments. You will have to use exec-maven-plugin like here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25442840/658606
And set up a call to that plugin in either "Project Properties / Actions" or "Run Maven/ Goals"