# Run spring boot jar with static content

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I'm using spring boot and storing my static content (html, css, etc.) as `src/main/webapp`. I understand that this is not recommended, because it won't be stored in jar file (should be in `/META-INF/resources/`, `/resources/`, `/static/`, `/public/`). But my question is not about storing static content in jar.

This is project structure:

```
App
 ├──src
 |   └───main
 |        ├── java
 |        |     └── ...
 |        ├── resources
 |        |     └── (everything here will be in jar)
 |        └── webapp <- this won't be in jar
 |               └── ...
 └ target
     └───App.jar
```

When I'm trying to run jar from `App` folder as `java -jar target/App.jar`, spring boot finds static content and works fine. However running it from `target` folder as `java -jar App.jar` won't find static content.

How to run `App.jar` from target folder and let spring boot find static content? Is it related to the classpath? I was trying to specify the classpath with `-cp` option, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a point of view that this is a build problem. I don't mean a *packaging* problem (I know you don't want to put it into the jar). But you have another option: your build system (e.g. Maven) can copy static files into the target folder.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16375537/5257399) demonstrates the use of `maven-antrun-plugin` to invoke Ant's `copy` command. This will put a copy of your static file into the `target` folder.

Obviously change the execution phase (test phase is too specific/late for your use-case).
And maybe lookup whether there's a more Maveny way to do it (since delegating to Ant is not super-idiomatic).

Comment: This plugin is copying single file. I found `maven-resources-plugin` and it can copy multiple resource directories to independent directories, but I don't think it is a good solution. I was thinking about something like changing working directory as you suggested, but think it's a dead-end.

Comment: out of curiosity: why don't you think build is a good way to solve this? `target` is the output of your project. everything you want to _ship_ or _run_ should get output into that folder. do you dislike having copies of the files? do you dislike having to keep them up-to-date? build should be invoked whenever source changes, so it's easy to keep things up-to-date. otherwise: the ant copy task can create symbolic links (though I don't recommend it).

Comment: Well, I agree with you. It's not that bad :) I was able to succeed by manually copying `webapp` folder to `target/src/main`. So I guess your option with maven plugin will work fine too. I am wondering is it the only way? I found `spring.resources.static-locations` property but not sure what should be there.

Comment: hm, I don't think `spring.resources.static-locations` can be used to specify an absolute path. its default value is `/**`, but that seems to refer to the root of the classpath or perhaps to the root of `usr.dir`. I don't think you can navigate upward from there.

Comment: I think copy static files into the target folder is simplest solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's searching relative to the working directory of the executable at runtime. Since it's using a relative path to lookup the file (e.g. `src/main/webapp/file.txt`), your working directory needs to be `/path/to/App`.

[You can change the working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9529800/5257399) using `-Duser.dir`.

I recommend trying this:

```bash
java -Duser.dir=../ -jar App.jar
```

Or maybe it needs to be an absolute path. Tell me whether it works; I've not got the project to try it out.

Comment: It does not work: "Error: Could not find or load main class .dir=../". I also tried `-Duser.dir=D:/App.`

Comment: Ah, it's Windows; maybe you need backslashes? ..\ or D:\App.
Depending on the shell you're using, you may need to escape these backslashes: ..\\ or D:\\App

Comment: if there's any ambiguity as to _where_ Spring Boot is searching, you can use [ProcMon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to snoop all file accesses on Windows. You can look for failed file lookups attempted by java, and this should tell you the absolute path to which it resolved your relative path. This will give an indication of whether `-Duser.dir` is having _any_ effect (and just needs a bit of tweaking), or if it's a dead-end.

Comment: I think `-Duser.dir` is having effect, because now I having this Error: Could not find or load main class org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.

Comment: @Birchlabs I think you need to merge these two answers, :)

Comment: @I_Am_Innocent why? they're different answers; they are two threads of discussion, either could be individually wrong or right, and either could be accepted as the preferred answer.

Comment: the other way to solve this is with an application-layer fix. `src/main/webapp/file.txt` is a relative path, so you need to either regain control of how it's resolved to an absolute path (there may even be a Spring Boot-specific way to do this), or you need to start referring to it using an absolute path. You could make this configurable, if you need it to be environment-agnostic.