# Execute commands using C in Android

Tags: android, c, linux

For some reason, I have to execute commands such as `ls`, `ps` using native c code in Android.

I tried `system()` and `popen()`, but none of them works. I don't know why.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Runtime.getRuntime().exec() to nav through directories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618631/android-runtime-getruntime-exec-to-nav-through-directories)

Comment: No, this is a different problem. I need to implement all this in c instead of java.