# From within a Rhino JS console run CD produces exception

Tags: windows, rhino, command-prompt

When attempting runCommand("cd", "..") from inside a js.jar console an IOException is thrown.
I believe it's because in the command prompt the CD command is actually built into the console and not a separate .exe file.  The runCommand("notepad") works fine, and that .exe can be found on the classpath in the usual location.

Is there a work around for this?

I was thinking that changing the directory through java instead of through the command prompt it might solve this problem, but I don't recall how to do that from java, but I plan on trying to figure that out.

To sum up: Is there a way to run "cd" from within a Rhino JS console on windows?

Thanks,
L-

Answer (score 0):

Multiple issues to solve here; it depends what you are trying to do.

`runCommand` actually runs executable programs. `cd` is not an executable on Windows; it is a command in the command shell. So you would need to execute something more like this:

```
runCommand("cmd","/c","cd <target-directory>")
```

However, the underlying Java runtime does not allow you to actually change the working directory anyway. See [this StackOverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840190/changing-the-current-working-directory-in-java). So shelling out `cd` just changes the directory for the subprocess (the process running `cd`), which is probably not what you want.