# Read File on Networkshare

Tags: java, file, networking, share, smb

I am running my Application from a network-share. For example: "\server\startProgramm.bat"
The Code in my startProgramm.bat:

```
java -jar %~dp0\app.jar
```

I need to open some config files. It is working local if i try to open them with:

```
new File("").getAbsolutePath() + "\\" + filename
```

but not on my Network share.

The config-files are in a subdir of the dir where my jar and bat files are.

Comment: how about `new File("\\\\servername\\sharedDirectoryOnServer\\fileOnServer")` ?

Comment: Ok, this worked, but is there something like CurrentWorkDir?

Comment: I guess you are getting a FileNotFoundException? Maybe the issue is related to that directory name? Try printing the path your program tries to read when running from that network share.

Comment: Current work dir is System.getProperty("user.dir").

Comment: Ok, i copied my comment to an answer for future reference and added what i found about the working directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new File("\\\\servername\\sharedDirectoryOnServer\\fileOnServer");
```

> "Ok, this worked, but is there something like CurrentWorkDir?"

The current working directory is (by default) the one your program runs in. You can **not** change it within java (see here: 
[Changing the current working directory in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840190/changing-the-current-working-directory-in-java)
),
the best practice is to just concatenate the server-path and file-name; but i think (not sure) it is also possible to start your program from the server (`java \\server\\path\\myprog` where there's a myprog.class in that directory) and make the working directory default to that path.