# Executing specific CMD commands from Java Code

Tags: java, compilation, cmd, runtime

I have a .java classfile with a main method which produces a file "output.txt".

I want to write a program in Java which compiles and runs it, so that the file "output.txt", produced by given Java class, is outputted to a specified folder. How can this be done?

I can compile and run it, but I couldn't make something like a `cd` command in Java. Showing absolute class in Java is not allowed.

Comment: Can you edit the code that creates `output.txt`?

Comment: I believe you are creating `output.txt` programmatically. So, just give the complete path of the file like `C:\myfolder\output.txt` instead of simply `output.txt` in your java code. If you can edit the code.

Comment: "Showing absolute class in java is not allowable"  Why not?  What do you mean by that statement?

Comment: C:\myfolder\output.txt is not allowable due to file specifications, only same folder output, cant be discussed. Also I cant modify Java class, it's like class which is been tested by it's output.

Comment: Your above comment is pretty unclear to me but anyways take a look at [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the current working directory in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840190/changing-the-current-working-directory-in-java)

Comment: I cant modify the java class, that'it. It is like input.

Comment: I don't understand "Showing absolute class" either. Can't you produce the file, and move it to the target dir later? Or call the class from the destination dir, giving the class's path in the - surprise - CLASSPATH?

Comment: I'll describe the application, it checks if submitted(uploaded) .java files after compiling and running with some "input.txt" produce a right "output.txt" and then show a result. It's a servlet, that means it's multithreaded app, so i cant store file in folder and then move, because if 2 users simultaneously upload, it can cause data unconsistency or loss.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `File` object pointing to the specified folder.

Then use `new File(file, "output.text")` to create a file object referencing "output.txt" in the folder pointed to above.  See  [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.io.File, java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to write a program in Java which compiles and runs it, so that the file "output.txt", produced by given Java class, is outputted to a specified folder. How can this be done?

Let's get this straight:

- The existing Java application `A` outputs a file `output.txt` ... somewhere.  You can't change that application.
- You want to write a application `B` that runs `A` in such a way that you can control the directory to which `output.txt` is written.

Q: Can it be done?

A: It depends on how `A` opens the output file.

- If `A` uses a *relative* pathname for the file; e.g. `new FileWriter(new File("output.txt"))` then it can be done; see below.
- If `A` uses an *absolute* pathname for the file; e.g. `new FileWriter(new File("/output.txt"))` then it *cannot* be done.  There's no practical way to cause `A` to put the file somewhere else.  (I wouldn't go so far as to say that it is theoretically impossible, but you'd need to resort to things that no sane developer would seriously contemplate doing.)

How you deal with the relative case is to have `B` use the `ProcessBuilder` to specify a different *current directory* for `A` when launching it.   The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) has an example that covers this; look for the use of `setDirectory` in the example ... and its specification.

(Note: you can also do this by running an external script that changes directory and runs the command.  But that approach involves platform specific things, and should be avoided if you want your code to be portable.)

Comment: Yes, it's relative, "new FileWriter(new File("output.txt"))", like that. Thanks for process builder hint.