# Terminal cd command not working from Scala script

Tags: shell, scala, io

I need to run a shell command from a Scala script and I use the following snippet for that:

```
import scala.sys.process.{Process, ProcessIO}

val command = "ls /tmp"
val process = Process(command)

val processIO = new ProcessIO(_ => (),
    stdout => scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(stdout).getLines.foreach(println),
    _ => ())
process.run(processIO)
```

The code works fine. I'm wondering why I get

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cd": error=2, No such file or directory
```

as soon as I change the command to `cd /tmp && ls` which is IMO equivalent to `ls /tmp`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Wikipedia on `cd` command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)#How_it_works):

> [...] on Unix systems `cd` calls the `chdir()` POSIX C function. This means that when the command is executed, **no new process is created** to migrate to the other directory as is the case with other commands such as `ls`. Instead, the shell itself executes this command.

There is even a quote about Java there:

> [...] neither the Java programming language nor the Java Virtual Machine supports `chdir()` directly; a change request remained open for over a decade while the team responsible for Java considered the alternatives, though by 2008 the request was denied after only limited support was introduced [...]

Try it yourself:

```
$ which ls
/bin/ls
$ which cd
$
```

In simple words, `cd` is not a program (process) you can run (like `/bin/ls`) - it is more of a command line directive.

What do you want to achieve? [Changing the current working directory in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840190) or change the working directory of the process you just created?

Comment: using `type cd` and `type ls` in the shell are also demonstrative in your shell.  It should report that cd is not an executable, but a shell built-in

Comment: Basicly I wanted to read an output of a certain command that should be run from a directory that is runtime known, like: `cd /somedir && find . -mindepth 5 -type d`. There's a number of ways to achieve it without `cd`, but having Perl background I was just curios why this was impossible to do with JVM. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Working solution:

```
import java.io.File
import scala.sys.process.{Process, ProcessIO}

object terminal_cd {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val command = "ls"
    val process = Process(command, new File("/tmp"))

    val processIO = new ProcessIO(_ => (),
      stdout => scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(stdout).getLines.foreach(println),
      _ => ())
    process.run(processIO)
  }
}
```

All you need is to replace `"cd /tmp"` with java.io.File instance as a working dir parameter.

(The method to be called: [/scala/src/library/scala/sys/process/Process.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/39148e4ec34a5c53443dd1b25ceec2308cd097fe/src/library/scala/sys/process/Process.scala#L72-L79) )