# change directory (CD) using ant script

Tags: ant, cd

How to change directory (CD) using ant script?Is there any task in ant which does:
cd

Comment: Please, explain what is the goal behind this for more productive answers.

Comment: I got a script in another directory ,I need to run that script.

Comment: Then `<exec dir="path" executable="..."/>`. What's the problem?

Comment: okay Thanks, I didnt know this can be done in one go.I was searching  how to change the directory and then run the script.:P:P

Answer (score 1):

> There is no way to do this in Java.

See [Changing the current working directory in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840190/changing-the-current-working-directory-in-java)

So ant can't do it either.

Current dir can only be changed for nested tasks like [java](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) forked in separate process with `fork="yes"`.

Comment: You can use `exec` to run some script that changes it's own current dir. But it would not reflect on ant's current dir.

Comment: I got a shell script in another directory and I want to execute it.