# Why was the file created in that path?

Tags: java, file, file-io, iostream

As a example:

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("c.txt"));
            try {
                os.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Why was `c.txt` generated in the root path of current project other then the same path of the java file?
 [image]

thanks.

Comment: The [Current Working Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) has *nothing* inherently to do with where the Java Source/Class file is located.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the root of your project is your current working directory when starting the JVM.
You can check the `user.dir` system property to see what is your current working directory. If you access a file without a leading slash (Unix) or drive specifier/backslash (Windows), the files will be created relative to your current working directory.

Comment: when I manually set the user.dir using System.setProperty("user.dir","c:\\xuhang");
Why wasn't the file generated in directory c:\\xuhang? Maybe I am wrong to test in this way.

Comment: You can not [change the current working directory on java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840190/changing-the-current-working-directory-in-java) by setting `user.dir`.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided a full path - this means that File constructor will use your process's current directory.

Answer (score 0):

The path you provided will point to the project directory only if you want to change you can
also you can mention the full path where file is to be generated.

```
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("c.txt"));

OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\c.txt"));
```