# Finding absolute path

Tags: java, file, relative-path, absolute-path

I am looking at code `new FileInputStream("config.properties")`.

I have the same file "config.properties" in multiple places in my project(doing windows file search) and I am now confused as to which one does this function call refer to. How do i get to know the **absolute path** of file?

I found this on the internet but this location doesnt look like the right answer.

`"ClassName".class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()` but this doesnt look it. Can you please correct it if I am wrong

Comment: use File file = new File("config.properties");file.getAbsolutePath();

Comment: Right. I was looking at FileInputStream class and tried if it had any method to find the absolute path but i can just pass the path name to File class and then find the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `File`:

```
File f = new File("config.properties");
System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

The path returned will be deduced from the current working directory.

Comment: thanks. Is there any way I can change and set a relative path for my program and start referencing other directories using that directory as base?

Comment: You can determine your program's current directory using `new File("")`. Then construct all path's from that.

Comment: sure. But can I change that reference point to some other directory which is more relevant?

Comment: @srujangulla, do you mean change the current working directory of the program? If so, I don't think it is possible (also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840190/changing-the-current-working-directory-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

```
File f = new File("config.properties");
String dirPath = file.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath()
```

Comment: thanks. Is there any way I can change and set a relative path for my program and start referencing other directories using that directory as base?