# Java "user.dir" property - what exactly does it mean?

Tags: java

I want to use `user.dir` dir as a base dir for my unit tests (that creates a lot of files). Is it correct that this property points to the current working directory (e.g. set by the 'cd' command)?

Comment: As stated in http://stackoverflow.com/a/840229/3159183, keep in mind that the `-Duser.dir` flag affects `File` objects (if they're not given a full path) but not `FileOutPutStream` objects. If you want to ensure the default directory matches for both, you should `cd` before you start Java.

Answer (score 186, accepted):

It's the directory where `java` was run from, where you started the JVM. Does not have to be within the user's home directory. It can be anywhere where the user has permission to run java.

So if you `cd` into `/somedir`, then run your program, `user.dir` will be `/somedir`.

A different property, `user.home`, refers to the user directory.  As in `/Users/myuser` or `/home/myuser` or `C:\Users\myuser`.

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) for a list of system properties and their descriptions.

Comment: Already read it before posting. But "User working directory" is not a best explanation, hope you agree.

Comment: Is that mean that on tomcat configuration for all java versions if `user.dir` is pointing to `/usr/share/tomcat` and in config we add something like this: `file:./config` then it will be pointing to `/usr/share/tomcat/config` always?

Answer (score 9):

`user.dir` is the "User working directory" according to the [Java Tutorial, System Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

Answer (score 8):

Typically this is the directory where your app (java) was started (working dir). "Typically" because it can be changed, eg when you run an app with `Runtime.exec(String[] cmdarray, String[] envp, File dir)`

Comment: A value is needed only during junit test execution by maven system.

Comment: and when you change it on the MAC, it breaks things like this test https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45130661/user-dir-property-broken-on-osx-jdk-1-8-0-111-how-about-other-os-versions :( :(

Answer (score 6):

`System.getProperty("user.dir")` fetches the directory or path of the workspace for the current project

Comment: It normally fetches the current working directory, like you get from the `pwd` command, but it looks like if you run with e.g. `mvn -f /path/to/project`, maven will effectively `cd /path/to/project` internally before running tests.