# Can't find the correct path for archive files inside a jar

Tags: java, jar

For a school project, i realized a program that simulates the archive of library.

One of my classes, FileManager.java, located in `\src\controller\`, reads from/writes in three files, containing the informations i need; for read/write I use a FileInputStream/FileOutputStream wrapped with an ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream, here is the code that writes data from the model into files, named `archive.users` and `archive.items`.

```
public void writeObjectIntoFile(final String fileName, final Model model) {
    try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(this.path + fileName))) {
            if (fileName.contains("users")) {
                oos.writeObject(model.getUserArchive());
            } else if (fileName.contains("items")) {
                oos.writeObject(model.getItemArchive());
            } 
        }
}
```

The variabile this.path is a String initialized with the path to the archive files, which are located in `\res\`, the variable is initialized this way:

```
private String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "res"
        + System.getProperty("file.separator");
```

And the class with the method `main`, called Application.java, which starts the program, is located in the folder `\src\controller\`.

My problem comes when i export the program into a .jar file, because it doesn't find my files anymore, and i cannot read the content of files to initialize the library archive or save new entries that i create with my GUI.

The problem is with the path or with the Streams?

Comment: Make sure you start your program in the correct directory. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239130/java-user-dir-property-what-exactly-does-it-mean

Comment: The jar should work in the same way in every folder, because the archive files are inside it, it just doesn't find them

Comment: Ah then you should be loading them as resources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861989/preferred-way-of-loading-resources-in-java