# Eclipse showing incorrect project path

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a maven web project in eclipse. I need to get the project's path, actually have to get list of files under `src\main\resources\someFolder` in project.

Tried `String dataDir = "src\\main\\resources\\someFolder";`, on running this directory structure is created inside eclipse folder like `F:\softwares\eclipse\eclipse\src\main\resources\someFolder`. Same when using `/` instead of `\\`.

Tried `System.getProperty("user.dir")`and `new File(".").getAbsolutePath()`, they return `F:\softwares\eclipse\eclipse`.

I need to access the project folder in my workspace `F:\workspace\Project\src\main\resources\someFolder`

But when created a core java app and used `System.getProperty("user.dir")`and `new File(".").getAbsolutePath()`, I am getting project path in workspace, `F:\workspace\Project`. This `src\\main\\resources\\someFolder` also works fine then.

Why this odd behavior from eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239130/java-user-dir-property-what-exactly-does-it-mean) the directory `user.dir` is the place where the JVM is started. As web applications are mostly jar/war/ear packages placed somewhere within the folder of the server eclipse handles them in a different way because the behaviour of such a web application is different. You cannot expect to have file access from outside the jar/war/ear file. Within the jar/war/ear file everything from within src/main/resources will be available just by using getResourceAsStream as described in many other stackoverflow articles. This way you mustn't use `src/main/resources/myfile.txt` but `myfile.txt`.

Don't try to guess or use what the user.dir / JVM/server start folder is!