# reading a file from a relative path in a maven project

Tags: java, maven, file-io, path, classpath

I have my java file in

> **/src/main/java/Test.java**

and I want to read a property file/XML file from

> **/src/main/resources/plugin.properties** and/or
>
> **/src/main/resources/templates/basic_java.xml**

When I try to read these files from Test.java (after deployment of course), it is not able to do so and giving the error

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /target/plugin.properties (No such file
>   or directory)
>           at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)

Though I can find the **plugin.properties** and **basic_java.xml** under **/target/classes** folder, yet it cannot read these files.

I have tried multiple solutions including :

```
1. getClass().getResource("Test.java");
2. new File(".").getCanonicalPath() + "target//plugin.properties";
3. ((URLClassLoader) Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()).getURLs()
4. ((URLClassLoader) Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()).getResourceAsStream("Test.java")
5. Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getSystemResources("Test.java");
6. new FileInputStream("src\\main\\resources\\plugin.properties");
7. new FileInputStream("resources\\plugin.properties");
8. new FileInputStream("src\\main\\resources\\plugin.properties");
9. new FileInputStream("\\plugin.properties");
10. new FileInputStream("\\classes\\plugin.properties");
```

but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
    InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/plugin.properties");
    String content = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
```

IOUtils is is from apache commons

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

This will open an input stream from the classpath.

Comment: Thank you so much...it worked... even with the sub - folders inside target/classes/template/java....

Answer (score 1):

Could you share more info?
From your error log

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /target/plugin.properties (No such file or directory) at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
```

It looks like you're looking the file in this path

> /target/plugin.properties

(that of course, doesn't exist). I think you have to do something like this

```
String pluginPath =System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/resources/plugin.properties";
```

In this case your program will search the file in

> pluginPath: /YOUR_USER_DIR/src/main/resources/plugin.properties

More info about "user.dir" [Java "user.dir" property - what exactly does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239130/java-user-dir-property-what-exactly-does-it-mean)