# JMeter Maven Plugin - How to provide external Properties file while running JUnit Performance Tests

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, blazemeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I want to run JUnit tests for the performance testing using JMeter Maven Plugin.

During the JUnit tests run, I use one external properties file located inside `<project>/src/resources/env.properties`

This file has some configuration which I need to run the tests successfully.

I have given this file in `src/test/jmeter` location as well but the plugin is not picking up this file.

During performance tests run using JMeter Maven Plugin, This file is not found because of the **relative path** given inside JUnit tests as

```
String fileName = "src/resources/env.properties";
```

I get the below error during the JMeter test run

```
[INFO] fileName = env.properties
[INFO] java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/resources/env.properties (No such file or directory)
```

Can you please help, where to give the location of this file? do I need to give in pom.xml?

These tests working perfectly fine using the JMeter application where I put this file under `<JMeterApp>/bin/src/resources` and run the test.

Please find below `pom.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>MyProject</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Generate JMeter configuration -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>configuration</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>configure</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Run JMeter tests -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Fail build on errors in test -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-check-results</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>results</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <generateReports>true</generateReports>
                    <jmeterExtensions>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins:pom:1.4.0</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-json:2.7</artifact>
                    </jmeterExtensions>
                    <junitLibraries>
                        <artifact>com:myProject:1.0-SNAPSHOT</artifact>
                    </junitLibraries>
                    <propertiesFilesDirectory>src/test/jmeter/src/resources</propertiesFilesDirectory>
                    <downloadExtensionDependencies>false</downloadExtensionDependencies>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Try to add `./` as `<propertiesFilesDirectory>./src`

Comment: added `./` in `<propertiesFilesDirectory>` but getting same issue

Answer (score 1):

When you run your tests via [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) the current [working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239130/java-user-dir-property-what-exactly-does-it-mean) looks like:

```
your_project\target\some-guid-like-structure\jmeter\bin
```

so in order to access the file which lives under `your_project\src\resources` you need to refer it like:

```
String fileName = "../../../../src/resources/env.properties";
```

More information: [How to Use the JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin)

Comment: I am unclear this part `String fileName = "../../../../src/resources/env.properties";` 
Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: `../` means go up a directory, so this is going up 4 directories to your project base directory.  There is also the the maven property `${project.basedir}` which could be used instead of traversing up the directory structure.  If you want to access it from java code create a properties file in your resources directory and define a property that looks like `baseDirectory=${project.basedir}`.  You can load in your properties file and use `props.get("baseDirectory")` to get the absolute URL of your project base directory.