# How to change the 'Open' button path in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

Is there a way to change the default path for OPEN button?
The first time I open Jmeter and clicks on 'Open file..' button,
the default path is "c:\Users\ <user_name>"

I want to change it to my "< jmeter scripts folder >" and not by changing user.dir parameter.

Dotan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of [JMeter 5.5](https://lists.apache.org/thread/k575c2oqnr0pv52fckcg399o4nkqt8c6) the "default" directory is being read from [`user.dir` property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239130/java-user-dir-property-what-exactly-does-it-mean)

[`setCurrentDirOnJFC(existingFileName, lastJFCDirectory, System.getProperty("user.dir"));`](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/gui/util/FileDialoger.java#L187)

So if you want to amend this value you need to set the `user.dir` property either by passing it to JMeter via `-D` command-line argument:

```
jmeter.bat -Duser.dir=c:/somefolder
```

or in order to make the change permanent you can add the relevant line to *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
user.dir=c:/somefolder
```

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thanks it works! ---- I try to avoid using 'user.dir' because I'm not sure if it's going to effect other parameters. In jmeter.properties file there's #proxy.binary.directory=user.dir. I'm not sure if it's critical.