# How to access files relative to the applications folder, independent of the current working directory?

Tags: java

I'm developing a Java SE 11 Maven project. In my project I have a folder called `assets` (it's a sibling of the `src` folder). This folder contains several folders and files. The whole folder has to be available at the application path - during development (in Netbeans) AND when it is deployed via an MSI package.

When running in the IDE, my assets live in `<projectRoot>/assets`, while my current working dir is `<projectRoot>`. And that's ok. I can access the assets folder via `./assets` from my current working directory.

But when I deploy my application, the current working directory might be something else, but not the application folder. So accessing the assets folder via `./assets` will fail.

What's the best approach in Java SE, to access a folder within the application's folder, independent of the current working directory?

Turning the `assets` into a resource folder is not an option, because the files must editable by the user. The `assets` folder has to reside directly in the file system.

Comment: rename it to `resources` and it will end up in your jar.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, that this is not an option in this case. See my edit above.

Comment: When the application is deployed, is the `assets` folder created as a subfolder of the root folder of the deployment? For example, if I deploy your application (on Windows) to `C:\Users\Abra`, will there be a `C:\Users\Abra\assets` folder?

Comment: `System.getProperty("user.dir")` will return the working directory.

Comment: There will be a folder like C:\Program Files\App\assets. But when my current working directory is D:\somewhere I can't access my folder using `./assets` because that would give me `D:\somewhere\assets` ...

Comment: What about defining an environment variable that stores the root folder of the deployed application like `ANT_HOME` which is required by [Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html) ?

Comment: How are you creating your MSI? I think there environment variables/ System properties that will tell you what the executable is.

Comment: there is also user.home https://stackoverflow.com/a/16239152/2067492

Comment: I'd store the assets as resources, but when the program starts, check for a `<user.home>/Appassets` directory, and if it doesn't exist, (i.e. the first time we start) create it and copy the resources to that directory and afterwards use them.

Comment: This would be very easy with `jpackage` application, but not easy to answer unless you give more info on the packager and what settings your application defines. The app ought to copy the reference version of `assets` to a user storage if not exists there. However there are plenty of different env settings which might be relevant depending on your circumstances and platforms. eg copy to `Path.of(System.getenv(XYZ), "assets")`)  where XYZ = "LOCALAPPDATA" | "APPDATA" |  "user.home" being a just a few of the choices.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your files/resources inside your source folder, you can access them through ClassName.getResource() and ClassName.getResourceAsStream() methods.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, that this is not an option in this case. See my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

use a config file or maven profiles (local and production)
in that config or profile define a folder where the files are

old anwser:
use Resources, the files in the jar (i assume your application is in a jar)
will be accessible using the

`URL url = Main.class.getResource("filename")`

or

`Inputstream stream = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("filename")`

replace 'Main' with your classname

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/class_getresourceasstream.htm

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, that this is not an option in this case. See my edit above.