# Query regarding Azure Load Testing using JMX Script

Tags: azure-devops, jmeter, load-testing, azure-load-testing

We are using Azure load testing for testing our application.

As a part of testing, we need to test one module which downloads PDF file and saves to my local folder using Apche Jmeter.

This download part works well on my local PC, and I could see the pdf files which are stored on my local path.

When I use the same jmx script in Azure Load testing, I am not sure where these pdf files will be saved.

Is there any alternate method which I can use for this?

Thanks

We tried with Apache JMeter which working fine, but not on azure load testing.

Answer (score 0):

If you use relative path (i.e. just file name) the files will go to the [current working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239130/java-user-dir-property-what-exactly-does-it-mean)

If you need to check integrity of the file like content you can tick `Save response as MD5 hash?` box in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler:

[image]

and then use [MD5Hex Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#MD5Hex_Assertion) for comparing MD5 checksum of the downloaded file with the expected one.

For any other test cases you can go for [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion)

More information: [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-assertions)