# Configure working directory of Scala worksheet

Tags: scala, worksheet, scala-ide

I would like the working directory for Scala worksheet (and the Scala interpreter) to be the Eclipse project path rather than the Eclipse installation directory. How can I (non programmatically) achieve that?

I know that I can use `System.setProperty("user.dir", "...")`, but IMHO that does not belong in the code. Further, it does not seem to work:

```
object ScratchWS {
  System.setProperty("user.dir", "C:\\")          //> res0: String = C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\eclipse
  new File("putty.exe").exists()                  //> res1: Boolean = false

  new File("C:\\putty.exe").exists()              //> res2: Boolean = true
}
```

Comment: Here are some issues logged against the project: [#102](https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-worksheet/issues/102), [#156](https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-worksheet/issues/156).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of Scala Worksheet 0.2.1 it is not possible to control the worksheet working directory.

For security reasons, once a JVM is running, it is not (directly) possible to change the JVM's working directly. See [Changing the current working directory in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840190/changing-the-current-working-directory-in-java) for details.

Therefore, it is generally good practice to always specify fully qualified paths, or specify relative paths from a fully qualified "anchor point".

Here's a hack I came up with for getting such an "anchor point" in the Scala Worksheet

```
object WorksheetProjectDirHack {
    // Yuck.... See: https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-worksheet/issues/102
    import Properties._
    val pathSep = propOrElse("path.separator", ":")
    val fileSep = propOrElse("file.separator", "/")
    val projectDir = javaClassPath.split(pathSep).
        filter(_.matches(".*worksheet.bin$")).head.
        split(fileSep).dropRight(2).mkString(fileSep)

    val otherProjectFile = new File(projectDir, "src/main/resources/data.bin")
}
```

It basically works by taking advantage of the the existence of the `.worksheet/bin` directory created in your Eclipse project directory and appended to the Scala Worksheet classpath.