# sbt and LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: java-native-interface, sbt

I need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH for an application using native DLLs. The reason is that I need to import two native DLLs, one depending on the other. JVM's -Djava.library.path only works for resolving the first library, but it's dependency is resolved using the dynamic loader policy, which is given by LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I use fork in test := true and fork in run := true. I use javaOptions ++= Seq(s"-Djava.library.path=...").

How do I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH? Meta-question: how do I navigate sbt APIs so I can learn how to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH on my own?

Comment: You can also use `System.loadLibary()` to explicitly load your dependencies.  That's probably easier than trying to set `LD_LIBRARy_PATH` or `PATH` (windows), which typically must be set in the environment.

Comment: I am using System.load(), via a third party jar. As I described above, that only works for the top level dll, not for its dependencies. Specifically, System.load() will find `libz3java.dylib` using `-Djava.library.path` or an absolute path, but will not load `libz3.dylib` it because the dylinker will fail. The only way to make `libz3.dylib` loadable as a dependency is via LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: Have you tried calling `System.load()` on `libz3.dylib` first?  You'll likely need an absolute path, but you'd have to inject that into `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` anyway.  BTW, on OSX you may need `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` instead of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Yes, I did. It doesn't work.

Comment: Seems like the problem may be [specific to OSX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776507/java-web-start-load-native-dependency-with-another-native-dependency).

Comment: It is, indeed an OS-specific problem. JVM's System.load() is a leaky abstraction. It exhibits on both Linux and OSX, and the solution is similar. Re-iterate the original questions: How do I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH using sbt?