# jython java PythonInterpreter

Tags: java, python, jython, pythoninterpreter

i need to run a python script in java, (using jython standalone jar) but when i run the script i got this error:

**ImportError: No module named pytesseract**

how can import python library, to run this script??

```
public class SimpleEmbedded {
public static void main(String []args){

  PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();
  System.out.println("Hello, world from Java");
  interp.execfile("text_rec.py");
  System.out.println("Goodbye ");
  }
}
```

I add also this piece of code:

```
interp = new PythonInterpreter(null, new PySystemState());
PySystemState sys = Py.getSystemState();
sys.path.append(new PyString(rootPath));
sys.path.append(new PyString(modulesDir));
```

what's *rootPath* and *ModulesDir*?

Can u help me??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing python modules in jython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256135/importing-python-modules-in-jython)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18975613/jython-configuring-modules-path-into-a-jython-script