# Change the place where Ebean generates the SQL

Tags: java, ebean

Well, the title says it all. By default Ebean generates the SQL files on the root of my project.
I want to place them on my resources folder, but I could not find any in the default config file, neither in the Ebean webpage, neither googling for it.

You guys know how to achieve this?

P.S - I'm not using Play, just Ebean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this isn't supported - i was looking for this feature myself and can't find any reference to an output directory in ServerConfig.java or the code that generates/writes the ddl itself.

you should be able to change the default working directory [programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13981910/1451524) to place the files elsewhere.

Comment: Wow!, was looking for a more simple way. But thank you, your solution haven't ever crossed my mind. I'll try this.

Comment: well - you could always submit a patch to the ebean folks :)