# Running a Bash Command in different directory from a java program

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell

**Program Description:**

I am writing a Java program which initial current directory is /home/user/Desktop. I want to run a bash command "du -s" in "location /home/user/project/" for finding the size of that folder so that I can to use the size of the folder in my project. I cannot post the entire code as it is having some sensitive data. I am just posting the code which is needed.

**Here is what I have done:-**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.File;

public class Exec_in_cur_dir {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
            String Command ="cd /home/user/project";   //Bash Command

            // create a process and execute 
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Command);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            String line = "";           

            while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");  
            } 

            System.out.println(output.toString());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So if I execute the program, the output is

> Cannot run program "cd": error=2.

But it is working every other commands like

- `ls`
- `df -h`
- etc.

**My Question:**

From the above analysis what I have inferred is my java program cannot be able to change directory. So how can I change the directory path and execute a bash command.

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840190/changing-the-current-working-directory-in-java

Comment: Why not just run du -s /home/user/project

Comment: Basically, use a `ProcessBuilder`, since with it you can specify the working directory of the forked process

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to clearly state the *why* you cannot do that, the `cd` command is not a program like ar `ls` or `df`. `cd` is directly interpreted by the shell (and the shell changes its own working directory what will be inherited but child commands), while for *programs*, the shell executes a `fork + exec` to execute the program as a new process.

When you use `runtime.exex()`, you start an new process to execute a program (and as already said `cd` is not a program). A common workaround to execute scripts (they too are not programs), is to use `bash -c command`. But it would be almost not use for you, because you would change the working directory of the child process only, and next `exec` would still have the working directory of the java program.

The only way to achieve that using `cd` command would be to change working directory in a shell, and have this shell execute the command. Something like :

```
    String Command ="bash -c (cd /home/user/project; du -s )";   //Bash Command
    // create a process and execute 
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Command);
```

But of course, the correct way it change working directory in `exec` command itself, avoiding to start an intermediary shell :

```
    String Command ="du -s";   //Bash Command
    // create a process and execute 
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Command, null, new File("/home/user/project");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't know that ls,df are programs, till now. Nice Exaplanation!

Answer (score 0):

I think correct form of writing above code is:-

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

   import java.io.IOException;

   import java.io.InputStream;

   import java.io.InputStreamReader;

   import java.io.File;



   public class Execute
   {

    public static void main (String args[])
    {

     String command="du -s";

     String output=executeCommand1(command);

     System.out.println(output);
    }
        public static String executeCommand1(String command) {

            StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

            Process p;

            try {
                File dir = new File("/home/user/project");//path
                p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command,null,dir);
                p.waitFor();
                BufferedReader reader = 
                            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                            String line = "";           
                while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return output.toString();

    }

  }
```