# run script from specific location programatically

Tags: java, runtime

I have a java class that runs any scripts on my server i require, and it works nicely.

I have an issue however, i need to run one script from a specific location and not sure how to do that. Is there a way to 'cd' to a directory before running my script in my java method?

My current method:

```
public String runScriptFile(String pathname) throws IOException{
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    String output="";
    Process proc = rt.exec(pathname);

    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
         InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
         InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

    String s = null;
    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        output+=s;
    }

    while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
        output+=s;
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697916/running-a-bash-command-in-different-directory-from-a-java-program

Comment: Yes that was indeed the same way i ended up solving it, probably a bit of a duplicate post so if you want to answer i'll mark ya as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [this SO answer can help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26698148/4130107)

You can set the working directory for the [exec method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File))

Answer (score 1):

Answer is to use the location param in Runtime.exec as follows

```
Process proc = rt.exec(pathname, null, new File("C:\\files\\"));
```