# Unable to located generated file

Tags: java, file, file-io

I am generating a file using the following syntax

```
File file = new File("input.txt");
```

The problem is that it is saying that it is writing to the file but I am not able to locate where the file is created, I searched my entire workspace. The expectation was that it would be created in the same folder as my code which is executing.

Any ideas?

Rest of the code :

```
        File file = new File("input.txt");

        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: why not try to specify a target location. just to make sure it generates the file :)

Comment: I tried giving it like this abc/input.txt where abc is a folder in my workspace, that did not help either, tried ./input.txt etc as well

Comment: If you're on Windows, look for C:\input.txt. That's happened to me

Comment: No, I am on Mac, but the OS shouldnt matter I guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a sop on the absolute path and you would get the path:

```
File file = new File("input.txt");
System.out.println("" + file.getAbsolutePath());

if (!file.exists()) {
    try {
    file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped in finding out that it is 
`/Users/username/Desktop/eclipse/Eclipse-EE.app/Contents/MacOS/input.txt` any idea on how I can move this to my workspace instead?

Comment: Specify the path as in: File file = new File("/Users/gaurav_khanna1/Documents/input.txt");

Comment: Yes, I tried that,but I want to give it a relative path instead of an absolute path.

Comment: that is a separate question from the earlier question in this thread. I would recommend asking a new question so as to get your answer quickly (but first check to see if that has already been asked before on this site.).

Answer (score 0):

When you create file through relative paths, Java uses `System.getProperty("user.dir")`. So, in your case the full path to file will be `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/input.txt");`.

Comment: Is it possible for me to update this user.dir and give it a custom value?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840190/changing-the-current-working-directory-in-java