# Cannot run program "...": CreateProcess error=2

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, execute

I am trying to execute a cmd command with java, but why does this command not work? When I try it in the windows cmd it works, but when I want to execute it with Java, it just doesn't work.

```
String cmd = "cd "+System.getenv("APPDATA")+"\\.minecraft"
Process pc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmds);
```

Do you know why?

//EDIT:
Error Message:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cd C:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Roaming.minecraft": CreateProcess error=2, File not found...
>       at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
>       at at.freakey.thundriallauncheerr.Launcher$SwingAction.actionPerformed(Launcher.java:313)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
>       at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ProcessImpl.(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
>       ... 41 more

Comment: Updated it with my total error log.

Comment: English only please.

Comment: Now it's english. Could you now help me please?

Comment: Error is pretty clear, do you have file at that location?

Comment: What is the exact command you run in windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cd` is not a program that you can execute. Even if you could it would do *nothing*.

When you `exec`, a new process is started. This new process is independent of your process (the Java process), and has it's own "current directory". Changing the current directory in that process will **not** affect the current directory of the Java process.

`cd` is a *built-in* command of the command-line program `cmd.exe`. To run a `cd` command, you need to run `cmd.exe /c cd ...`. But as I just stated above, it would be meaningless (the process would end immediately).

As for changing the current directory of the Java process, see this: [Changing the current working directory in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840190/changing-the-current-working-directory-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I think that exec is checking if file "cd C:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Roaming.minecraft" exists.

Instead of executing "cd C:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Roaming.minecraft" use proper version of exec method:

```
exec(java.lang.String command, java.lang.String[] envp,java.io.File workDir)
```

for example:

```
exec("executablefilename", null, "C:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Roaming.minecraft")
```