# Change java working directory when running WildFly

Tags: java, wildfly, working-directory

I'm trying to change the java working directory, which means, I'm trying to change `user.dir` property.

For instance, the code below will create a file called foo in my `user.dir` directory.

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("foo.txt");     
out.write("foo".getBytes());
out.close();
```

If I want this file to be created in another directory, that is not the dir that I have ran java command I need to use `System.setProperty`, in my case I want

`System.setProperty("user.dir", System.getProperty("jboss.server.temp.dir"));`

But this doesn't work, I think it's because I'm using `FileOutputStream` instead of File

**If I run WildFly through eclipse plugin, I can set a working directory path, this way everything works as expected. See the image**

[image]

I've tried to put `-Duser.dir=%JBOSS_HOME%\standalone\tmp` inside `standalone.bat` script, but doesn't affect at all.
The actual working directory is `%JBOSS_HOME%\bin`, the place where `java -jar` is called

My question: How can I change the working directory for java running on wildfly and working for `FileOutputStream`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840190/changing-the-current-working-directory-in-java - in short, you can't do it reliably.  I would use a different variable (system or environment)

Comment: @stdunbar I understand that this has not a trivial solution, and based on the difficult that I'm having to find answers I must be going on the wrong way. How can I make the programmer to not be awere of absolut paths or system variables on FileOutputStream constructor? And why with that option in eclipse plugin works? thank you

Comment: Ultimately the question is where do you want to put the file?  Can you safely assume that the O/S user running Wildfly will have permission to do this?  I might do a "FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir" + System.getProperty("file.separator ") + "foo.txt");" to put the file in the **Java** temporary directory, handling Windows vs. Unix.  But I have to ask - why does a web server write a file?  Shouldn't it stream it back?  If it is send by a user, shouldn't it go, for example, in a database?

Comment: I want to put a file in a temporary place like wildfly /tmp dir. It will be some files for inter-systems integration, one system can read this files for a while. There are many systems on my company using new FileOutputStream("foo.txt"); and I should find a solution that don't aware to paths in the source code.