# Why a Java file exists only in its canonical form?

Tags: java

I'm facing a strange behaviour of the JVM. I wanted to change the user directory, i.e. the dir where files are looked up, that normally corresponds to the path where the `java` command is run.

So I wrote the following code:

```
System.setProperty("user.dir", "/tmp/");
File f = new File("myfile");
System.out.println(f.exists());
System.out.println(f.getCanonicalFile().exists());
```

The file `/tmp/myfile` exists and is readable by the JVM, but if I'm **not** in `/tmp/` when I run that code, the result is:

```
false
true
```

They are the same file, Java is able to retrieve the correct canonical form of it, but the relative one does not exist, while the canonical one exists.

**Is it a bug? Is there a way to reliably change the JVM user directory?**

Changing the code is not an option, as I'm trying to run external libraries.

Comment: Are you sure that the change of System variables is immediately recognised by the JVM?

Comment: You can try to override it during startup with -Duser.dir=/tmp/. I suppose that somewhere in native filesystem code this information is being cached early. I don't think it is something which should be changed during runtime - how existing File instances should behave in such case?

Comment: Just FWIW, I've been able to verify the behavior. The documentation of `exists` is really quite minimal; it doesn't say it's going to resolve a relative path before checking and, well, apparently it doesn't.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840190/changing-the-current-working-directory-in-java - Changing the working directory using `System.setProperty()` or giving jvm argument is not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 5):

This behavior is normal, the reason is, there is a difference between

```
File f = new File("myfile");
```

and

```
File cf = new File("myfile").getCanonicalFile();
```

The first denotes a filepath relative to your current WORKING DIR, which could be your project path. Using the relative path, the `user.dir` property is NOT USED, even when setting `user.dir` as JVM parameter `-Duser.dir=/tmp/`. The resolution of Java file handles to native file entities is done natively by the underlying Fileystem implementation.

But when invoking `getCanoncialFile()` before resolving the native file handle the relative path is resolved using the user path information - in your case `user.dir = /tmp/`.

Apparently, there is no file `myfile` in `<WORKING_DIR>` but in `/tmp/`.

The behavior is the same for `f.getAbsoluteFile()`.