# How to set file path dynamically in Java program?

Tags: java, file

I want to dynamically set the document root in a program in Java. My Java program accepts 2 inputs:

1. document root path as String
2. an Int which I'm using for some
   calculations.

I set this document root in program, so that any use of `File file=new File(filename)` will fetch the specified file from the document root path:

```
String f_path=args[0]; //within main().
```

`f_path` could be any path in that system other than the root directory of the program.
Currently, when I do `File file=new File(filename);` it searches for the specified file in the program's root directory. How can I change this to `f_path`?

Comment: `File file=new File(f_path);`?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840190/changing-the-current-working-directory-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `File` constructor which takes a parent parameter : [File(String parent, String child )](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) , e.g :

```
File file=new File(f_path, fileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should craft absolute paths, for example using the `File(String parent, String path)` constructor :

```
new File(f_path, filename)
```