# Setting Working directory for a project

Tags: java, eclipse

I am initiating a session of an external application in my java code. I set the working directory to the bin of the particular application via eclipse debug configurations.And by doing this I am able to launch my application
Right now I wanted to generate a runnable jar out of this. How can I set the working directory for this via code or is there any other way I can achieve this?
This is what I tried and it is not working.I am getting java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError.

```
File file=new File(".");
    System.out.println("Current Working Directory: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    System.setProperty("user.dir", GetPropData.getInputDataMappingsElements("pathtext"));
    System.out.println("New Current Working Directory: " + file.getAbsolutePath()
```

What is the alternative of setting the work space directory in eclipse?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the current working directory in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840190/changing-the-current-working-directory-in-java)

Comment: @Berger I think it's more than that. A more mature way is to accept the working directory path as a parameter and default to "user.dir" system property if none is given. I use Spring so `@Value` injection. However, it can also be achieved through pure Java.