# Running java app from the command line with a different working directory

Tags: java, command-line

Is it possible to run a java application from the command line and specifying a working directory for it?

I tried using the -Duser.dir argument like this:

```
java -Duser.dir=<some directory> -jar <some jar>
```

but it didn't help...

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/840229/281460. As Michael Myers suggests in that post, I don't think there is a reliable way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a path of your app to the classpath and run the app:

```
java -classpath <path to your app> <your app file name>
```